# Вопрос по методу Instantiate() в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо сделать так, что бы при смерти моего главного героя на этом месте появлялся объект - его душа. Почему то в данный момент получается так что его "Душа" "инстантиэйтится" в месте коардинат 0,0,0, хотя задано место где находится в данный момент gameobject главного героя.

```
public GameObject GhostPref;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Gnome.dead)
    {
        var b = GameObject.Find("Prototype Body");
        var t = this.transform.rotation;

        Debug.Log(b.transform.position);
        Debug.Log("Сработал инстантиэйт");
        Instantiate(GhostPref,b.transform.position,t);
        Debug.Log(b.transform.position);
        Gnome.dead = false;
    }
}
```

Причем Debug.Log(b.transform.position); показывает именно те координаты где и должен появляться объект, но появляется он именно в координатах 0,0,0.

Cам скрипт находится в компонентах объекта из которого хочу запустить Instantiate();

Если пишу так:

```
if(Gnome.dead)
{
         Instantiate(Ghostpref);
         Gnome.dead = false;
}
```

ситуация никак не изменяется. Ghostpref появляется в координатах 0,0,0.

Пробовал разные способы, получилось только так:

```
if (Gnome.dead)
{
    var body = GameObject.Find("Prototype Body");
    var ghost = Instantiate(GhostPref).transform;
    ghost.SetParent(body.transform);
}
```

теперь объект ghost появляется в нужном мне месте, но мне нужно что бы объект был независимым и не двигался вместе с объектом body когда он двигается.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше не дергать Instantiate просто так, это крайне дорого. Сделайте EmptyObject и внутри проложите две модели, одной уберите active галку и включайте через SetActive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Debug.Log(b.transform.position);
Instantiate(GhostPref,b.transform.localPosition,t);
```

> Причем Debug.Log(b.transform.position); показывает именно те
>   координаты где и должен появляться объект

В лог вы пишите `position`, а присваиваете `localPosition`. Не перепутали `тёплое` с `мягким`.

Comment: Пробовал и так и так, итог одинаковый.